# How to catch an error message and send it by EMail?

Tags: sql-server, database, syntax-error, email-attachments, database-administration

Now when I take a backup I received error the problem not in error the problem in 
How can I catch this body of the error message and send it by EMail or insert it into a table

I have stored for Backup

```
EXEC dbo.dothebackup2;
```

After execution I received this error:

```
Msg 3206, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Backup device 'Professor_Tape' does not exist. To view existing backup devices, use the sys.backup_devices catalog view. To create a new backup device use either sp_addumpdevice or SQL Server Management Studio.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

Now how can I save this message in the table?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this task.

1 - Wrap the call to the backup stored procedure in a SQL Agent job.  On failure of the job step, alert a operator, your DBA distribution list to react to the issue.

The Agent automatically keeps history by time or physical file size.  See this [MSDN article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190956.aspx) on how to adjust the rentention period.

Check out this [MSDN article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191130.aspx) on how to notify an operator of a job status.

2 - Check out some of the more professional free backup solutions.  I use the [Ola Hallengren](http://ola.hallengren.com/) scripts for backups, index maintenance and consistency checks.

I hope this helps you.

Sincerely

John